# jquery passing single value arrays via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've seen a lot of posts about how to pass arrays via ajax in jquery.  This is not exactly about those questions.  Is the following reasonable behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

I have some simple jquery ...

```
var changedIds = new Array();
...
changedIds.push(123);
...
$.post({
    url: url,
    data: {
        ids: changedIds
    },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true
}).done(function(ajaxData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    window.location.reload();
}).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Submit Fail: ");
});
```

The `changedIds` array will end up with 0-N integers in it.  I check the `.length` before the POST so a zero length array is not sent.  My question is about what happens when there is only ONE value.

It appears that having a single value array treats the "array" like a plain variable.  The HTTP request lists the data as:

```
ids=123
```

The target of this ajax call is a .Net `ActionResult` method that wants an array value.  It pouts and throws an exception if it is handed what looks like a plain variable.

I have started checking the array `.length` and if it is 1 then pushing in a known dummy value so that there are two values for the array.  This seems to work -- but is this correct behaviour?  Is this the best work-around?

Comment: Is your service expecting JSON in the request body?

Comment: Don't know really.  I'm pretty new to the .NET game.  It is an ActionResult method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try serializing your data parameter using `JSON.stringify` and specifying a `contentType` of `application/json` as follows:

```
var changedIds = new Array();
...
changedIds.push(123);
...
$.post({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        ids: changedIds
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true
}).done(function(ajaxData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    window.location.reload();
}).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Submit Fail: ");
});
```

That should convert the JavaScript object into valid JSON and tell the server the type of data that you are sending.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I had tried the stringify but not in that way.  Thanks